# Сделать копии файлов пропуская неизмененные (linux)

Tags: bash

Есть папка с копиями файлов **dir2** (очень много файлов), также есть папка с оригиналами этих файлов **dir1**. иногда в файлы, находящиеся в папке **dir1** производятся изменения, которые отображаются в свойстве файла (например: изменен 16.12.2016 в 16:40). Время от времени **делается копия всех файлов** из **dir1** в **dir2**,это занимает очень много времени. Как написать bash-скрипт, который бы проверял, изменился ли оригинальный файл в **dir1** и переписывал бы его в **dir2**, а файл, который не изменялся - пропускал? Может это реально реализовать через обычный **cp**? я не обнаружил в нем ключа пропуска, в случае нахождения одинаковых "ПО ДАТЕ ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ" файлов. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp -u
```

> -u, --update Copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing.

[cp](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать утилиту rsync.

rsync -a /dir1/ /dir2

первый раз создаст точную копию директории, все последующие разы будет копировать только изменившиеся с момента последней синхронизации файлы

Comment: можно добавить рекурсивное копирование и сохранение модификации --recursive --times